Custom PCB based on the Adafruit PyBadge with Multiple SPI interfaces for SD Card and other devices
I'm currently working on a tracking device with multiple sensors on a custom PCB. The device uses Narrowband LTE, SPI flash, and an SD card, all managed by an ATSAMD51J19A microcontroller. To streamline development.
Based on past experiences, I encountered issues using a single SPI bus to handle both sensors and the SD card simultaneously, which led to conflicts and performance problems. To address this, I created a custom SPI bus named SD_SPI by following the instructions in this great manual.
However, when I tried to initialize the SD card using the custom SPI bus, the initialization always failed. To troubleshoot, I switched to a software SPI implementation, and the SD card worked immediately without any issues. This suggests that the problem might be related to the setup of the SDFAT library.
I suspect the problem to be somewhere in the SD configuration since i haven't found any example of what i'm trying to do so i just did
#define SD_CONFIG SdSpiConfig(SD_CS_PIN, DEDICATED_SPI, SD_SCK_MHZ(1), &SD_SPI)

I'm hoping for advice from someone more knowledgeable.

#include "SdFat.h"
#include "wiring_private.h"
#include <Arduino.h> 
#include <SPI.h>

#if SPI_DRIVER_SELECT == 0  // Must be set in SdFat/SdFatConfig.h

// SD_FAT_TYPE = 0 for SdFat/File as defined in SdFatConfig.h,
// 1 for FAT16/FAT32, 2 for exFAT, 3 for FAT16/FAT32 and exFAT.
#define SD_FAT_TYPE 3
//
// Chip select may be constant or RAM variable.
const uint8_t SD_CS_PIN = 5;
//
// Pin numbers in templates must be constants.
const uint8_t MISO_PIN = 6;
const uint8_t MOSI_PIN = 9;
const uint8_t SCK_PIN = 28;

// SdFat custom SPI template
SPIClass SD_SPI(&sercom1, MISO_PIN, SCK_PIN, MOSI_PIN, SPI_PAD_2_SCK_3, SERCOM_RX_PAD_2);

#if ENABLE_DEDICATED_SPI
#define SD_CONFIG SdSpiConfig(SD_CS_PIN, DEDICATED_SPI, SD_SCK_MHZ(1), &SD_SPI)

#else  // ENABLE_DEDICATED_SPI
#define SD_CONFIG SdSpiConfig(SD_CS_PIN, SHARED_SPI, SD_SCK_MHZ(0), &SD_SPI)
#endif  // ENABLE_DEDICATED_SPI

#if SD_FAT_TYPE == 0
SdFat sd;
File file;
#elif SD_FAT_TYPE == 1
SdFat32 sd;
File32 file;
#elif SD_FAT_TYPE == 2
SdExFat sd;
ExFile file;
#elif SD_FAT_TYPE == 3
SdFs sd;
FsFile file;
#else  // SD_FAT_TYPE
#error Invalid SD_FAT_TYPE
#endif  // SD_FAT_TYPE

void setup() {
  // turn on the SD-Card
  pinMode(43,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(43, HIGH);
  delay(5000);

  SD_SPI.begin();
  delay(200);

  pinPeripheral(6, PIO_SERCOM);    // SD_SPI MISO
  pinPeripheral(28, PIO_SERCOM);   // SD_SPI MOSI
  pinPeripheral(9, PIO_SERCOM);    // SD_SPI SCK

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Wait for USB Serial
  while (!Serial) {
    yield();
  }
  Serial.println("Type any character to start");
  while (!Serial.available()) {
    yield();
  }

  Serial.println("starting");
  delay(500);
  if (!sd.begin(SD_CONFIG)) {
    sd.initErrorHalt();
  }

  if (!file.open("HARDSPI.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT)) {
    sd.errorHalt(F("open failed"));
  }
  file.println(F("This line was printed using software SPI."));

  file.rewind();

  while (file.available()) {
    Serial.write(file.read());
  }

  file.close();

  Serial.println(F("Done."));
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void loop() {}
#else  // SPI_DRIVER_SELECT
#error SPI_DRIVER_SELECT must be two in SdFat/SdFatConfig.h
#endif  // SPI_DRIVER_SELECT


If you are using the SPI bus for multiple devices, it might help to switch to SHARED_SPI instead of DEDICATED_SPI in your SdSpiConfig: #define SD_CONFIG SdSpiConfig(SD_CS_PIN, SHARED_SPI, SD_SCK_MHZ(0), &SD_SPI)
